# SQL giving a pourcentage

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, percentage

I've made this request in French. I'm not sure that you need the database DB for that. I'm using ORACLE

I just want to multiply avg(Taux_remplissage) or MOY x 100 because I want it as a percentage. How should I do ?

```
SELECT numC , sum(prix) as Cout_Tot , avg(Taux_remplissage) as MOY
FROM
(
SELECT P.numC , P.dateDep , C.prix  ,nbRes , nbPlaces , ( R.nbRes / 
P.nbPlaces) as Taux_remplissage
FROM lesProgrammations P
JOIN lesReservations R ON R.numC = P.numC AND R.dateDep = P.dateDep  
JOIN lesCircuits C ON P.numC = C.numC
ORDER BY P.numC , P.dateDep
)
GROUP BY numC
ORDER BY numC;
```

EDIT : 
Thanks for ur help ! I found the solution :)

```
avg(Taux_remplissage) * 100 / sum(Taux_remplissage) AS Taux_moy_remplissage
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Why doesn't `avg(Taux_remplissage) * 100` do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a subquery for this:

```
SELECT numC, sum(prix) as Cout_Tot,
       (100 * avg(R.nbRes / P.nbPlaces)) as MOY
FROM lesProgrammations P JOIN
     lesReservations R
     ON R.numC = P.numC AND R.dateDep = P.dateDep JOIN 
     lesCircuits C
     ON P.numC = C.numC
GROUP BY numC
ORDER BY numC;
```

In addition, `ORDER BY` is not appropriate for the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

try like below just multiply `avg(Taux_remplissage)*100`

```
SELECT numC , sum(prix) as Cout_Tot , avg(Taux_remplissage)*100 as MOY
FROM
(
SELECT P.numC , P.dateDep , C.prix  ,nbRes , nbPlaces , ( R.nbRes / 
P.nbPlaces) as Taux_remplissage
FROM lesProgrammations P
JOIN lesReservations R ON R.numC = P.numC AND R.dateDep = P.dateDep  
JOIN lesCircuits C ON P.numC = C.numC
ORDER BY P.numC , P.dateDep
)
GROUP BY numC
ORDER BY numC;
```